# the correct way to transform gif images to png images

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I am trying to transform images from gif format to png format. This is how I did

```
 def _gif_to_png(gif_dir, png_dir):  
    img_names = tf.gfile.ListDirectory(gif_dir)

     for f in img_names:
    # get the filename without the extension
     basename = os.path.basename(f).split(".")[0]

     im = Image.open(os.path.join(gif_dir,f))
     transparency = im.info['transparency'] 
     png_file_name = os.path.join(png_dir, basename+'.png')
     im.save(png_file_name, transparency=transparency)
     png_names = tf.gfile.ListDirectory(png_dir)
```

However, I got the following error message

```
 transparency = im.info['transparency']
KeyError: 'transparency'
```

What might be the problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

That happens when your GIF does not contain transparency.

> `transparency`
>   Transparency color index. This key is omitted if the image is not transparent.
>   (http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/handbook/image-file-formats.html#gif)

How do you know if a GIF contains transparent pixels? Apparently, the way you did – by testing if that key exists. You can directly test it, surrounded by a `try..except`, or with

```
if 'transparency' in im.info.dict():
   .. do stuff ..
```

Comment: so, for this case, I just need to use  im.save(png_file_name) without the the option of transparency, is that right?